# Backing up Exchange 2010

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup, exchange, exchange-2010

Does anybody know if Exchange 2010 will support backup using the native tools?

We are still using Exchange 2003, however I'm aware that backing up Exchange 2007 on server 2008 isn't possible with the native tools.

I understand this will be addressed shortly in an update to Exchange 2007, however does anybody know if Exchange 2010 will address this out of the box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for now there is no definite answer as to whether Exchange 2010 will work directly with NTBackup. If you look at the [Exchange 2010 Backup SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd877010(EXCHG.140).aspx) it indicates that Exchange 2010 will remove the ability to do streaming backups, which is what NTBackup currently uses to backup Exchange, and will require block level backups, so if NTBackup is to work with Exchange its going to need to be able to do that. This said, this is the same reason you cannot do Exchange backups in server 2008, so if they are fixing that in the next SP, then it should work for 2010 as well, unless they are just re-enabling streaming backups in 2008.

This said, Exchange 2010 does have a very comprehensive backup SDK so if NTBackup does not work I'm sure there will be plenty of people writing solutions to solve this, or alternative applications to do the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Since Service Pack 2 of Exchange Server 2007 will introduce native backup on Windows Server 2008, I expect that the feature will be available in Exchange Server 2010 too.

> At TechEd 2009, the announcement was
>   made that a VSS-based plug-in for
>   Windows Server Backup in Windows
>   Server 2008 will be included in
>   **Exchange 2007 SP2 (coming Q3 2009)**.
>   This plug-in lets customers take
>   Exchange-aware VSS backups on Windows
>   Server 2008. This plug-in offers
>   certain capabilities in Exchange
>   Server 2007 SP2.

Source: [Exchange Server 2007 SP2 reinstates built-in backup capabilities](http://searchexchange.techtarget.com/tip/0,289483,sid43_gci1358731,00.html)

Answer (score 3):

For anyone using you favourite 'Net search engine, Microsoft have an article that explains how you can [Use Windows Server Backup to Perform a Backup of Exchange](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd876854.aspx) . Windows Server Backup is a feature of Windows Server 2008 / 2008 r2 which you need to manually add/install.